# Bootstrap 4 - displaying cards in a custom way

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a proper semantic HTML/CSS based on Bootstrap 4 that would present card elements in a certain way without adding too much custom bulk.

What I have so far is this:

```
<section class="section d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row news-block">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
          <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
          <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Test 1</h4>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple mb-4">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 2</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 3</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 4</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 5</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 6</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 7</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

A Codepen to see what I mean: https://codepen.io/wiwa-cloud/pen/rKxqYw?editors=1100

What I'd like to achieve:

- the same spacing (Vertical & horizontal) between all cards
- the "big" card on the left should be the same height as the right column with 6 cards
- keep it responsive

Is there a good 'bootstrap 4' way of doing this, or do I need to hack around pretty much?

Also, should I wrap everything in .card-deck and if so, why? (I'm using card-deck for when cards stay horizontally stacked on other custom components).

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap 4 [utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/) to adjust the layout...

- `h-100` to make the left card full-height to match the smaller cards
- `p-2` spacing (padding) to make even gutter between columns

https://www.codeply.com/go/CPe58ZHi2u

```
<section class="section d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row news-block py-1">
      <div class="col-md-5 p-2">
        <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple h-100">
          <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
          <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Test 1</h4>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 2</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 3</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 4</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 5</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 6</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 7</h4>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also, `p-3` could be used instead of `p-2` if you want a larger gutter.

Comment: TY, I was overcomplicating things it seems and forgot about the h-100! Seems like bootstrap 4 thought of it already :)

Answer (score 0):

he answered before i finished but here's another version of what he did haha

```
<section class="section d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row m-0 news-block pt-3 pl-3">
      <div class="col-md-5 mb-3 pl-0 pr-3 pr-md-0">
        <div class="card h-100 text-center pt-3 card-simple">
          <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
          <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Test 1</h4>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 pl-0 pl-md-3 pr-0">
        <div class="row mx-0">

          <div class="col-md-4 pl-0 pr-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple h-100">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 2</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 pl-0 pr-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple h-100">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 3</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="col-md-4 pl-0 pr-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple h-100">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 4</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 pl-0 pr-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple h-100">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 5</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 pl-0 pr-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple h-100">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 6</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 pl-0 pr-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card text-center pt-3 card-simple h-100">
              <a href="#GO" class="click-overlay"></a>
              <img class="card-img-top w-75 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Test 7</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>







        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/chulps/pen/PaZgNO

Comment: Ty, can you put it in a forked pen, so I can compare the options. Now I'm changing font-size of the smaller cards and it doesnt work very well on all screens with the accepted answer, perhaps it might with yours.

Comment: Edit! Added link to bottom